# How to reset the specific input field with either the entered amount and total sum amount from buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a working **sum amount** and **reset button for specific field** that only works when not inside a **form tag** but I need to put all the input fields and amount buttons inside a form tag so there would be a validation before submit.

The process should be like this:

-When the customer click multiple buttons with specified amount, the total amount will display on a field.

-When customer click the reset, the specific field should be reset.

But the problem is that when the total amount displayed on the field is reset then the customer click a button again, **the amount will just add to the total that was cleared**. But when I remove the form tag, the reset button is actually working but the validation on submit button will not work.

So what would be the alternative way to do if I don't remove the form tag?

My codes and jsfiddle is attached bellow:

```js
//Total Amount Sum Calculator
var sum = 0;

function f(val){
  sum += val;
  document.getElementById("deposit-total").value = sum;
}
function reset(){
  sum = 0;
  document.getElementById("deposit-total").value = 0;
}

//Automatic Comma
function FormatCurrency(ctrl) {
            //Check if arrow keys are pressed - we want to allow navigation around textbox using arrow keys
            if (event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 40) {
                return;
            }

            var val = ctrl.value;

            val = val.replace(/,/g, "")
            ctrl.value = "";
            val += '';
            x = val.split('.');
            x1 = x[0];
            x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';

            var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;

            while (rgx.test(x1)) {
                x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
            }

            ctrl.value = x1 + x2;
        }
//Restrict Characters (Numbers Only)
        function CheckNumeric() {
            return event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57 || event.keyCode == 46;
        }

function submitForm() {
  return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="number" class="input-char-amo" id="deposit-total" step="10000" min="10000" max="5000000" onkeypress="return CheckNumeric()"  required>
              <button type="reset" id="reset" class="correction" onclick="reset()">reset</button><br>
              <div class="amount-buttons-a">
              <button type="button"  id="1" onclick="f(10000)" class="btn-amount">10000</button>
              <button type="button"  id="2" onclick="f(20000)" class="btn-amount">20000</button>
              <button type="button"  id="3" onclick="f(50000)" class="btn-amount">50000</button>
            </div>
            <div class="amount-buttons-b">
              <button type="button"  id="4" onclick="f(100000)" class="btn-amount">100000</button>
              <button type="button"  id="5" onclick="f(500000)" class="btn-amount">500000</button>
              <button type="button"  id="6" onclick="f(1000000)" class="btn-amount">1000000</button>
            </div>
  
  <p class="check-acc">input here</p>
          <input type="text" class="input-check-acc" id="check-account" required>
  <br>
<button id="dep-submit" value="submit" type="submit" >신청 </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Rename function reset() as it is already a javascript function by default. When you call that you aren't actually doing your method.

Comment: Made sense now. Thank youuu. It's working but do you also have idea on how to exclude other fields in reset? the id of the total field is already in the js but it still works on other field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the work for you , you cant use reset at function since is used by default from js

```js
//Total Amount Sum Calculator
var sum = 0;


function f(val){
  sum += val;
  document.getElementById("deposit-total").value = sum;
};

function resets(){

  sum = 0;
  document.getElementById("deposit-total").value = 0;


}

//Automatic Comma
function FormatCurrency(ctrl) {
            //Check if arrow keys are pressed - we want to allow navigation around textbox using arrow keys
            if (event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 40) {
                return;
            }

            var val = ctrl.value;

            val = val.replace(/,/g, "")
            ctrl.value = "";
            val += '';
            x = val.split('.');
            x1 = x[0];
            x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';

            var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;

            while (rgx.test(x1)) {
                x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
            }

            ctrl.value = x1 + x2;
        }
//Restrict Characters (Numbers Only)
        function CheckNumeric() {
            return event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57 || event.keyCode == 46;
        }

function submitForm() {
  return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="number" class="input-char-amo" id="deposit-total" step="10000" min="10000" max="5000000" onkeypress="return CheckNumeric()"  required>
              <button type="reset" id="reset" class="correction" onclick="resets()">reset</button><br>
              <div class="amount-buttons-a">
              <button type="button"  id="1" onclick="f(10000)" class="btn-amount">10000</button>
              <button type="button"  id="2" onclick="f(20000)" class="btn-amount">20000</button>
              <button type="button"  id="3" onclick="f(50000)" class="btn-amount">50000</button>
            </div>
            <div class="amount-buttons-b">
              <button type="button"  id="4" onclick="f(100000)" class="btn-amount">100000</button>
              <button type="button"  id="5" onclick="f(500000)" class="btn-amount">500000</button>
              <button type="button"  id="6" onclick="f(1000000)" class="btn-amount">1000000</button>
            </div>
  
  <p class="check-acc">input here</p>
          <input type="text" class="input-check-acc" id="check-account" required>
  <br>
<button id="dep-submit" value="submit" type="submit" >신청 </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Ohh that's why! thank you. But I would also just like to have a reset button in the total amount. Not on other fields in the form or that field below. Do you also have any idea or explanation on how to do that? The id was already in the declared in resets().

Comment: Do you want a total and a sum.

Comment: i didnt get what you asking for

Comment: Tracks each increase from 0 and then adds to a total amount?

Comment: What I'm mean was the reset button also reset other fields too, it should be just the total amount field.

Answer (score 0):

`reset` is a reserved keyword for javascript. If you want to see all reserved words, please look that [link](http://%20https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp).

Just change the function name of `reset()` to another name.